# C# Deselect COMobject WordDocument

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, selection, office-interop

In Visual Studio I've created a Word 2016 Document project. To this document I've added a custom ActionsPane control. The only thing this control does is adding a PlainTextContentControl to the active document.

```
if (Globals.ThisDocument.Content.Application.ActiveDocument == null) return;
        var tagControl = Globals.ThisDocument.Controls.AddPlainTextContentControl(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
tagControl.PlaceholderText = @"PLACEHOLDER";
tagControl.LockContents = true;
```

This all works fine, the plaintextcontrol is added and selected in the Word document. But what I want is that the control is added and that the cursor will jump to the end of the control so a user can directly start typing. The newly added control is automatically selected. How can I turn this of?

I have already tried:

```
var range = Globals.ThisDocument.Content;
range.Application.Selection.Collapse();
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

Edit:
Als tried this solution.

```
private static IntPtr documentHandle;
        public delegate bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern System.IntPtr SetFocus(System.IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumChildProc callback, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder title, int count);

        private static bool EnumChildWindow_Handle(IntPtr handle, int lparam)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(50);
            GetWindowText(handle, s, 50);
            Debug.WriteLine(s.ToString());
            if (s.ToString() == "Microsoft Word-document")
            {
                documentHandle = handle;
            }
            return true;
        }

 private void MoveCursorToEndOfLastAddedTag(PlainTextContentControl ctrl)
        {
            EnumChildProc EnumChildWindow = new EnumChildProc(EnumChildWindow_Handle);
            EnumChildWindows(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, EnumChildWindow, 0);
            SetFocus(documentHandle);
}
```

This also doesn't work.

Comment: Your last code snippet isn't making a lot of sense, especially since the default behavior of Collapse is wdCollapseStart. Is the content control the last thing in the document? What happens if you alter your code so that it's finished after the control is inserted (selection in the control), then you press Right-Arrow in the Word UI? Does that give you the result you're looking for? FWIW normally I'd expect something like the following to work: Word.Range rng ? tagControl.InnerObject.Range; object oCollapse = Word.Wd.ColllapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd; rng.Collapse(ref oCollapse); rng.Select();

Comment: Hello Cindy, indeed when the control is added to the Word document and I press the right-arrow key it gives me the desired looking. The cursor is now after the added control.. I'll try your code parts and let you know.

Comment: I've changed the code into:

Comment: I've moved what you posted as "Answer" into your Question since only something that answers your question should be in an "Answer". This is something you should do yourself, another time; simply click the "Edit" link below your question in order to edit it.

Comment: "Not the desired result": You need to be SPECIFIC in how it's "not working". And, yes, the focus will be in the Actions Pane when the user works in it and from what I can recall it's not possible to move the focus back to the document programmatically. Certainly not with the Word/VSTO object models, although the Windows API could possibly manage it. The user has to click back on the document (or press Ctrl+F6 until focus cycles back to the document after running through all the Ribbons, etc.)

Comment: @CindyMeister, thank you for helping me. The desired result is when a user clicks a button (this will be changed later on to something else) there has to be placed a plaintext content control in the word document. When the control is placed en the user starts typing, the characters should appear after the plaintext contentcontrol and not in it (because it's readonly, it will not work). Maybe I use the wrong contentcontrol or something. What I described here is what I want. Does this clarify the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have success. It's not the most clean way, but it works like a charm. The only code I made is this:

```
private void MoveCursorToEndOfLastAddedTag(PlainTextContentControl ctrl)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F10}");
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F10}");
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
}
```

It sends 2 times the F10 key. First time the focus is set to the ribbon, the second time the focus is given back to the document. With the right key I remove  the selection from the PlainTextContentControl.

Thank you all for your help.